# Transforming dataframe into expanded matrix in r

Tags: r, matrix

Say I have the following dataframe:

```
dfx <- data.frame(Var1=c("A", "B", "C", "D", "B", "C", "D", "C", "D", "D"),
           Var2=c("E", "E", "E", "E", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C"),
           Var1out = c(1,-1,-1,-1,1,-1,-1,1,-1,-1),
           Var2out= c(-1,1,1,1,-1,1,1,-1,1,1))

dfx

   Var1 Var2 Var1out Var2out
1     A    E       1      -1
2     B    E      -1       1
3     C    E      -1       1
4     D    E      -1       1
5     B    A       1      -1
6     C    A      -1       1
7     D    A      -1       1
8     C    B       1      -1
9     D    B      -1       1
10    D    C      -1       1
```

What you see here are 10 rows that correspond to match-ups between players A, B, C, D and E.  They play each other once and the winner of each match-up is denoted by a +1 and the loser of each match-up is denoted by a -1 (put into the respective column Player Var1 result in Var1out, Player Var2 result in Var2out).

**Desired output.**

I wish to transform this dataframe to this output matrix (the order of rows are not important to me, but as you can see each row refers to a unique match-up):

```
       A     B     C     D     E
1      1     0     0     0    -1
2      0    -1     0     0     1
3      0     0    -1     0     1
4      0     0     0    -1     1
5     -1     1     0     0     0
6      1     0    -1     0     0
7      1     0     0    -1     0
8      0    -1     1     0     0
9      0     1     0    -1     0
10     0     0     1    -1     0
```

**What I've done:**

I managed to make this matrix in a roundabout way.  As roundabout ways tend to be slow and less satisfactory, I was wondering if anyone can spot a better way.

I first made sure that my two columns containing players had factor levels that contained every possible player that ever occurs (you'll note for instance that player E never occurs in Var1).

```
#  Making sure Var1 and Var2 have same factor levels
levs <- unique(c(levels(dfx$Var1), levels(dfx$Var2))) #get all possible levels of factors
dfx$Var1 <- factor(dfx$Var1, levels=levs)
dfx$Var2 <- factor(dfx$Var2, levels=levs)
```

I next split the dataframe into two - one for Var1 and Var1out, and one for Var2 and Var2out:

```
library(dplyr)
temp.Var1 <- dfx %>% select(Var1, Var1out)
temp.Var2 <- dfx %>% select(Var2, Var2out)
```

Here I use `model.matrix` to expand columns by factor level:

```
mat.Var1<-with(temp.Var1, data.frame(model.matrix(~Var1+0)))
mat.Var2<-with(temp.Var2, data.frame(model.matrix(~Var2+0)))
```

I then replace for each row the column with a '1' indicating the presence of that factor, with the correct result and add these matrices:

```
mat1 <- apply(mat.Var1, 2, function(x) ifelse(x==1, x<-temp.Var1$Var1out, x<-0)   )
mat2 <- apply(mat.Var2, 2, function(x) ifelse(x==1, x<-temp.Var2$Var2out, x<-0)   )

matX <- mat1+mat2

matX

   Var1A Var1B Var1C Var1D Var1E
1      1     0     0     0    -1
2      0    -1     0     0     1
3      0     0    -1     0     1
4      0     0     0    -1     1
5     -1     1     0     0     0
6      1     0    -1     0     0
7      1     0     0    -1     0
8      0    -1     1     0     0
9      0     1     0    -1     0
10     0     0     1    -1     0
```

Although this works, I have a sense that I am probably missing simpler solutions for this problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an empty matrix and use matrix indexing to fill the relevant values in:

```
cols <- unique(unlist(dfx[1:2]))
M <- matrix(0, nrow = nrow(dfx), ncol = length(cols), dimnames = list(NULL, cols))
M[cbind(sequence(nrow(dfx)), match(dfx$Var1, cols))] <- dfx$Var1out
M[cbind(sequence(nrow(dfx)), match(dfx$Var2, cols))] <- dfx$Var2out
M
#        A  B  C  D  E
#  [1,]  1  0  0  0 -1
#  [2,]  0 -1  0  0  1
#  [3,]  0  0 -1  0  1
#  [4,]  0  0  0 -1  1
#  [5,] -1  1  0  0  0
#  [6,]  1  0 -1  0  0
#  [7,]  1  0  0 -1  0
#  [8,]  0 -1  1  0  0
#  [9,]  0  1  0 -1  0
# [10,]  0  0  1 -1  0
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to use `acast`

```
 library(reshape2)
  #added `use.names=FALSE` from @Ananda Mahto's comments 
 dfy <- data.frame(Var=unlist(dfx[,1:2], use.names=FALSE), 
            VarOut=unlist(dfx[,3:4], use.names=FALSE), indx=1:nrow(dfx))


 acast(dfy, indx~Var, value.var="VarOut", fill=0)
 #    A  B  C  D  E
 #1   1  0  0  0 -1
 #2   0 -1  0  0  1
 #3   0  0 -1  0  1
 #4   0  0  0 -1  1
 #5  -1  1  0  0  0
 #6   1  0 -1  0  0
 #7   1  0  0 -1  0
 #8   0 -1  1  0  0
 #9   0  1  0 -1  0
 #10  0  0  1 -1  0
```

Or use `spread`

```
 library(tidyr)
 spread(dfy,Var, VarOut , fill=0)[,-1]
 #    A  B  C  D  E
 #1   1  0  0  0 -1
 #2   0 -1  0  0  1
 #3   0  0 -1  0  1
 #4   0  0  0 -1  1
 #5  -1  1  0  0  0
 #6   1  0 -1  0  0
 #7   1  0  0 -1  0
 #8   0 -1  1  0  0
 #9   0  1  0 -1  0
 #10  0  0  1 -1  0
```

Comment: After seeing this answer, I realized that if the OP doesn't mind renaming their columns, they can use `merged.stack` from my "splitstackshape" package. See [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/98175d209b642ee39ae9), with timings.

Comment: @Ananda Mahto Thanks for the timings.  I was a little surprised that `spread` is not that fast.  Perhaps, `dcast.data.table` would be a better alternative.

Comment: Presently, ~ 45% of the time in your function is spent with the "`unlist`" step. That drops ***dramatically*** with `use.names = FALSE`... but still doesn't stand a chance against the matrix indexing approach :-)